# 3 column layout with flex column direction

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid, masonry

I am trying to build a view of items which are mapped using React. The goal is to have a 3 column layout with items arranged in column direction. Each panel has a hidden div inside, once the panel is clicked the div is expanded. The idea being that this will push content down in **that column only.**

I've experimented with a grid version and currently trying bootstrap with traditional `row, col` flex properties using percentages.

For ease I have made two examples, just using jquery to mimic the click functionality.

First with grid: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/vmaut95L/

Basic css:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2em 2em;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

The issue here is when you click the item with hidden content (panel 3) all the panels get expanded to the same size.

Here is the bootstrap version: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/u83L6tph/

This is better, but when I change the flex direction to column everything appears in one column, left aligned with is 33% width (`col-md-4`). This is using standard bootstrap css as can be seen in the fiddle.

The markup is similar but uses more bootstrap utility classes:

```
<div class="row exclusive-offers-wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-4 mx-n1 p-4">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>
...
```

The goal is to have something which behaves like this:
[image]

Comment: Understood both the example, but what exactly is needed ? The functionality of bootstrap is needed in your css-grid ? or you just want your css-grid to expand properly on click of item 3 ?

Comment: I thought css grid would achieve what I want. But after testing this I don't think it will. The grid I assume will always line up. I don't know if setting `height: 0`, and/or `overflow: hidden` on the collapsed container would work. So I was fairly certain I would have to abandon grid layout and stick with bootstrap. But I am not 100% sure. If it can be done in grid that is fine. Although my preference would be to stick with bootstrap as I have a better knowledge of it.

Comment: I was wondering about a masonry style layout but that is done with JS which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite a full answer but it does satisfy several requirements. I started checking Bootstrap 4 Cards: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns

It seems with some very simple markup it is possible to create a masonry style layout. The only issue now is that when I click on one of the cards to display the hidden content some of them potentially jump around (click the first item in the fiddle).

I made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/avfpq1sr/

Basic markup:

```
<div class='card-columns'>
  <div>
    <div class='card item'>
      <h4>A heading</h4>
      <div class="hidden">
        <p class="mt-4 mb-5">Save up to 20% off* your business insurance thanks to....</p>
        <a href="https://www.goodlight.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/goodlight-commercial-led-lighting.png" title="View" class="sc-pFZIQ iVCQdF cta btn-primary" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card item'>
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of hidden `display:none` I have tried using `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` on the hidden content but same result.

If anyone has any experience of this I would like to hear. I will see if I can update the tags in the question.